# awk - подскажите как выбрать поле

Tags: linux, awk

Текстовый документ со строками вида:

```
000023:AAAB:1111111111111111111122:ABCC:428.15
000025:KCC::В11111111111111111356782:BBC::434.83
```

нужно вырезать на awk отдельно третий столбец, который начинается после второго разделителя `:` , в приведенном примере то есть нужно вырезать:

```
1111111111111111111122
В11111111111111111356782
```

командой `awk -F":" '{ print $3 }'` вырезается некорректно из-за сдвоенного разделителя `::`, который в документе часто наряду с одним `:`
Указать жестко начальную позицию искомого поля можно - оно одинаковое по всей таблице, но длина его варьируется, поэтому указать от и до не получается.
Искомое поле может начинаться как на букву, так и на цифру.
Подскажите как вырезать.
Придумалось `| sed 's/\::/:/g' | awk -F":" '{ print $3 }'` - а без sed одним awk можно обойтись?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для команды awk в качестве разделителя можно указывать регулярное выражение. Поэтому вы можете написать например так

```
awk -F':+' '{ print $3 }'
```

Либо в качестве альтернативы можно так(разделитель `:` или `::`)

```
awk -F':|::' '{ print $3 }'
```

Comment: да, оба работают, спасибо, буду знать!